# C# memory read/write running external app from Loader app

Tags: c#, pointers, external, read-write

I have a Loader application and another application that I wan't to allow to only be started from the Loader. I did this before with C++. All I did was declare a dummy string in the external app like so:

```
string dummy = "something";
```

Then in the main() of the external app:

```
if (string != "changed") return;
```

Using a memory read/write library I took the offset of the dummy string value (e.g 0x4F6C87) and from the Loader upon starting the application it writes "changed" to the application memory so that way it changes the string and the application starts.

I need a similar way of doing this in C#. Basically I only have trouble with getting the offset from the string (it could be int too or anything else that can be changed). I know how to get pointer, but it's not what I am looking for as the pointer changes every time the application is started, so I need the static offset (e.g 0x4F6C87) of the variable. Thank you!

Comment: I know how to read the address of the variable, but in C# the address is always changing upon each program run. Is there even a way to make the address fixed/static? I tried to save the address output in a text file, then in the other app read the text file and store the value in an integer value, but looks impossible to read 0x4F6C87 from text file and store it in integer. Any ideas here? Help!